# Count frequencies with logical condition

Tags: r

Here is the R code.

```
illdate<-c("2009-05-26","2010-12-03","2011-06-05","2010-08-10","2009-05-14","2010-01-08","2012-08-07","2010-11-13","2013-06-06","2010-08-26")

Treated<-c("T","T","N","T","N","N","T","T","T","N")

Reason<-c("Finish","Finish","Dead","Dead","Cured","Cured","Finish","Finish","Dead","Cured")

Enddate<-c("2009-12-12","2011-05-08","2011-02-28","2010-10-30","2011-10-08","2011-03-03","2013-05-05","2011-05-06","2014-08-08","2012-07-07")

number<-c(1:10)

mydata<-data.frame(number,illdate,Treated,Reason,Enddate)
```

And I want to count the number of cases that fit  the logical conditions:

```
1:illdate between "2010-01-01" and "2010-12-31"

2:Treated= "T"

3:Reason= "Finish" & "Cured"

4:Enddate between "2011-01-01" and "2012-12-31"
```

Please tell me how to write the code in R. Thank you very much.

Comment: What approach have you tried up until now? This forum is not a place for generic code generation.

Comment: Just do `mydata %>% filter(between(illdate, "2010-01-01", ""2010-12-31"), Treated == "T", Reason %in% c("Finish", "Cured"), between(Enddate, "2011-01-01", "2012-12-31"))`  change to `as.Date("2010-01-01")` if needed

Comment: @akrun you should add that as answer

Comment: Do you want all the conditions in the same time or one by one ?

Comment: @akrun Thank you, I will try it now. :-)

Comment: @OrhanYazar In the same time.:-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, maybe less beautiful:

```
   nrow(subset(mydata,"2010-01-01" < as.Date(illdate) & as.Date(illdate) < "2010-12-31" &
   Treated == "T" & Reason %in% c("Finish", "Cured") & 
   "2011-01-01" < as.Date(Enddate) & as.Date(Enddate) < "2012-12-31"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
res <- mydata %>%
         mutate_at(vars(matches("date")),  as.Date) %>%
         filter(between(illdate, as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2010-12-31")),
          Treated == "T",
          Reason %in% c("Finish", "Cured"),
          between(Enddate, as.Date("2011-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31")))

dim(res)
#[1] 2 5
```